# Minimum number of edges to add in order to have a biclique cover

Tags: graph-theory, covering, bipartite-graphs

Given a bipartite graph G and a number N, what's the minimum number of edges I have to **add** to G in order to be able to cover the resulting graph with no more than N complete bipartite subgraphs?

For example, consider the bipartite graph A1 - B1, A1 - B2, A1 - B3, A2 - B1, A2 - B3, A3 - B1, A3 - B2, A3 - B3, A4 - B4, A4 - B5, A5 - B4, and N = 2. The answer would be 2, because by adding A2 - B2 and A5 - B5, I can cover the graph with the biclique (A1 A2 A3 x B1 B2 B3) and (A4 A5 x B4 B5).

I can't seem to find the class of problems this is called - everything I find is about covering with subgraphs, but I actually want an over-cover while creating few extra edges. Anybody enlighten me? :)

Comment: Only tangentially relevant: what comes to mind is the classical concept of Dushnik and Miller of representing a poset as the intersection of linear orderings on the same ground set. This is different, yet somehow in the same spirit: analysing a structure in terms of simpler_over_structures. See Dushnik--Miller: Partially Ordered sets, American Journal of Mathematics 63 (1941), perhaps this might help.

Answer (score 1):

The kind of problem you are looking is called *graph editing problems*. There are many variations but, in general, in such kind of problem you are given a graph $G$ and you are asked the minimum number of edges (or vertices) you have do remove (or add, or both) in order to the graph satisfy a certain property $\Pi$.

A very close example of your question is the [The Bicluster Graph
Editing Problem](http://acgt.cs.tau.ac.il/theses/noga_msc.pdf).